# Duplicate values table gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to use a table in a gridview, but I have a problem.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid" 
        DataKeyNames="ABI" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="pics/plus.png" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="gvOrders" runat="server" CssClass = "ChildGrid" Text="aa">

                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ButtonField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataTextField="N017" HeaderText="Contact Name"/>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="N028" HeaderText="City" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I expand and click on the ButtonField, page automatically will be reloaded and in the textbox I have the duplicate values.
What's wrong?

Comment: Consider changing ButtonField into a TemplateField (you can convert it through aspx designer). This gives you more visibility of what is happening and control to change behaviour. With the added control you can decide if you really want an asp.net button that automatically is bound to make a postback when clicked - or if you simply want an e.g. static html <input... /> instead that you can wire up using javascript.
It's not 100% clear to me what you want to achieve - that's also why I can't aid with code example as answer.

Comment: Are you checking the `IsPostBack` property when data-binding your gridview?